# Calculating all possible "time difference" combinations in R

Tags: difftime

I'm using camera trapping data which contains two columns:

- "datetime" of when the photo was taken
- "species" species that appears in the photo

I want to calculate time difference between all possible pairs of species in R.

I have used difftime and diff functions in R but the result obtained isn't what I aim, as R is calculating time between "datetime2-datetime1", "datetime3-datetime2", "datetime4-datetime3", etc.

An example of my data is:

datetime (POSIXct format): "2018-10-06 08:39:00", "2018-10-07 04:09:00",          "2018-10-14 00:47:00"

species: "deer", "horse", "fox"

If I use diff function:
`diff(datetime)`

Time differences in hours

[1]  19.5000 164.6333 #this shows time between first and second and second and third datetimes.

#

I have also tried:

```
base_time <- datetime[1] 
later_times <- datetime[2:3]  

later_times - base_time 

diff(later_times)
```

This option combines all possible datetimes but it doesnt make sense if my data set has more than 3 rows...

As I need to calculate time difference between all photos, this should be:

"datetime2-datetime1", "datetime3-datetime1", "datetime4-datetime1",

"datetime3-datetime2", "datetime4-datetime3", etc.

I'm still learning R, so any help would be greatly appreciated!